# How to sum a column over a subset of rows in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

i hope i can describe my problem in an understandable way.

So i got a table of logging events like so:

| id | event | count | marker |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EVENT 1 | 3 | false |
| 2 | EVENT 1 | 2 | false |
| 3 | EVENT 2 | 4 | false |
| 4 | EVENT 1 | 1 | true |
| 5 | EVENT 1 | 6 | false |
| 6 | EVENT 1 | 2 | true |
| 7 | EVENT 1 | 5 | false |
| 8 | EVENT 2 | 3 | true |
| 9 | EVENT 1 | 3 | false |
| 10 | EVENT 2 | 5 | false |

What i want is the sum of the column 'count' of all rows newer (higher id) than the last occurence of a true in the column marker distinct for every event.

I was able to get that result for each event individually like so (example for 'event 1'):

```
select sum(count) from test_table
    where event='EVENT 1'
    and id > (select id from test_table 
    where event='EVENT 1' 
    and marker=1
    order by id desc limit 1);
```

The result for this query would be 8 (sum of lines 7 and 9), 5 for the query for 'EVENT 2' respectively (sum of the line 10).

But now I want to get these results in one query like so:

| event | sum |
| --- | --- |
| EVENT 1 | 8 |
| EVENT 2 | 5 |

Is that possible? I played around with window functions a bit, but didn't get the desired result.

I hope, someone can help me.

Greetings
Frank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What i want is the sum of the column 'count' of all rows newer (higher id) than the last occurence of a true in the column marker distinct for every event.

One method is:

```
select event, sum(count)
from t
where id > (select max(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.event = t.event and marker)
group by event
```

Comment: Argl ... didn't expect it to be that simple :D. Thanks very much for your quick answer!